# Как биндить клавиши MIDI-контроллера в Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

В Python 3.8 с модулем tkinter root.bind работает со стандартной клавиатурой, но при подключении MIDI-контроллера (в моём случае Arturia Beatstep) я не могу найти имя клавиши. keysym не даёт результат

Comment: вряд ли можно ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554896/getting-input-from-midi-devices-live-python